# Showing that $e^{-|x|^2}$ is in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but not in $\mathcal{C}_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying rigorously to prove that $e^{-|x|^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is in the Schwartz space but not in the space of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support.

The function $e^{-|x|^2}$ is in $\mathcal{S}$.

Proof: From the fact that for any polynomial $p$, $p(x)e^{-|x|^2}$ is bounded and for any multi index $\beta$, $D^{\beta}(e^{-|x|^2})=p_{\beta}(x)e^{-|x|^2}$ for some polynomial $p_{\beta}$ we have to
$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} |x^{\alpha}D^{\beta}(e^{-|x|^2})|<\infty$.

**Affirmation 1**. $(\forall \beta$ multi index)($\exists p_{\beta}$ polynomial)($D^{\beta}(e^{-|x|^2})=p_{\beta}(x)e^{-|x|^2})$

Proof: It is true for $|\beta|=0$ and $|\beta|=1$.

Suppose true for any multiindex with large $l$.
Let $\gamma=\beta+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon=(0,\ldots, 1,0,\ldots )$ with 1 in the $j$-esime position.

\begin{eqnarray} D^{\gamma}(e^{-|x|^2})&=&D^{\epsilon} D^{\beta}(e^{-|x|^2}\\
&=&\partial_{x_j}(p_{\beta}(x)e^{-|x|^2})\\
&=&[\partial_{x_j}(p_{\beta}(x)]e^{-|x|^2}+p_{\beta}(x)[\partial_{x_j}(e^{-|x|^2})\\
&=&q_{\beta}(x)e^{-|x|^2}+p_{\beta}(x)(-2x_j)e^{-|x|^2}
\end{eqnarray}

**Affirmation 2**. For any $p$ polynomial, $p(x)e^{-|x|^2}$ is bounded.

Proof: $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} \frac{p(x)}{e^{|x|^2}}=0$ then for any $M>0$ exists $R>0$: $|x|>R$ implies $|p(x)e^{-|x|^2}|<M$.

Therefore, in $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|x|>R\right\}$, $p(x)e^{-|x|^2}$ is bounded.

From the fact that $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|x|\leq R\right\}$ is compact and $p(x)e^{-|x|^2}$ continuous we have that  $p(x)e^{-|x|^2} $is bounded for $|x|\leq R.$

Now I would like to prove that the function $e^{-|x|^2}$ is not in $\mathcal{C}_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Is it because the function is not differentiable at the origin?

Thanks.

Comment: It is differentiable.  But it is not $0$ for sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: Define $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb R^{n})$. With the definition I have, $e^{-|x|^{2}}$ does belong to this space.

Comment: $\mathcal{C}_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$:the set of all infinitely differentiable functions on $R^n$ with compact support
[Wong, An introduction to pseudo differential operators, page 12]

Comment: thanks. $\text{supp}(e^{-|\cdot|^2})=\mathbb{R}^n$ not compact

Comment: Given that you computed the derivatives (for all $x$) earlier, it's a bit strange that you seem to believe that the function is not differentiable at the origin. In that case, it wouldn't belong to the Schwartz space either, right?

Comment: @ Hans Lundmark Yes. I was confused when I said that. It was my mistake but now I understand.